# How can I find a lawyer who can create an international will in Japan?

Tags: legal, japan, australian-citizens

I am an Australian living in Japan.

Japan and Australia both are signatories to [Unidroit](https://www.unidroit.org/instruments/international-will/), so an international will should be possible. I assume I need a lawyer for that. How can I find a lawyer to prepare an international will?

Answer (score 3):

The best way to find a lawyer as an expat in Japan (or elsewhere) is to ask other expats with the same background as you if they have hired a lawyer for a similar reason in the past. If so, and they were they satisfied with their work, could they put you in touch, etc.

If you don't have expat friends with a similar background who could provide solid leads, or you already have tried this angle and it wasn't sufficient, another good option always is a country-specific Chamber of Commerce.

For an Australian, in particular, that would be the [Australian & New Zealand Chamber of Commerce in Japan](https://www.anzccj.jp/). Attending one of their [networking events](https://www.anzccj.jp/events/) would be a first step to finding an applicable attorney (and building your network in general). You also could refer to the Australian Embassy [directory of lawyers by location](https://japan.embassy.gov.au/tkyo/legal.html), which provides a list of attorneys not only in major cities in Japan, but also in smaller ones, as well.